# docsIfCmStatusDocsisOperMode deprecated in DOCSIS 3.0

Tags: snmp, oid, docsis

I need to query the current mode a CM has registered to a CMTS in DOCSIS 3.0 using SNMP.

The OID used for that in DOCSIS <= 2.0 is [docsIfCmStatusDocsisOperMode](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=docsIfCmStatusDocsisOperMode), but it has been deprecated for use in DOCSIS 3.0 and no (clear) alternative exists that I'm aware of.

Does anyone know what OID should be used to get the CM's current operation mode in DOCSIS 3.0? At least some pointer as to why this was deprecated would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same info can be queried through the OID [docsIf3CmtsCmRegStatusQosVersion](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.4491.2.1.20.1.3.1.13) on the CMTS the CM has registered with.

I was, initially, assuming that the operation mode referred to the "DOCSIS version" the connection was operating in, but it actually is the connection mode as the spec states: *"DOCSIS 1.1 QoS or DOCSIS 1.0 CoS mode"*. So, don't make the same mistake I did, there just is no way to get the "DOCSIS mode" because there is none.